# Move the line below up to the previous line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need help to move the line from the text below up to the previous line using the Notepad++.

Is there a regex that I can use for that?

```
PID: AIR-CAP3502I-T-K9,  VID: V01,  SN: 0000000000
                                                   Inventory for XXXXXXXXXXX
PID: AIR-CAP3502I-T-K9,  VID: V01,  SN: 0000000000
                                                   Inventory for XXXXXXXXXXX
PID: AIR-CAP3502I-T-K9,  VID: V01,  SN: 0000000000
```

[enter image description here]

TM

I tried to use some regex, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
Search: \n(.+)$
Replace: $1

Search: \n(.+)
Replace: $1
```

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://superuser.com/

Comment: @Rob you're not wrong, but to be fair, this is a question about regular expressions, which is on topic - it just happens to be in the context of this one application, but the question is generally just asking how to perform a regex replacement here.

Comment: @Rob I believe Notepad++ questions are on-topic under the [programming tools exemption](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Nick That's looking for loopholes. You also can't ask about helicopter maintenance just because a helicopter has a computer on it.

Comment: @Rob are you saying Notepad++ is not a programming tool? Perhaps exemption was the wrong word, the help specifically says that questions about programming tools *are* on-topic

Comment: I'm saying Notepad++ is a text editor. @Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to move the `Inventory for` lines to the previous lines, separated by a space, you could use the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    \R\s{5,}
Replace: (single space)
```

### Demo

Explanation of pattern:

- `\R` match LF `\n` or CRLF `\r\n`
- `\s{5,}` then match 5 or more spaces (arbitary) leading the next line

Then, we replace with just a single separating space.

Comment: Note typo in the last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

If the previous line should be a single line, and you don't want to move empty lines or lines that consist only of spaces, you could capture at least a single non whitespace characters in group 1 and match the preceding newline surrounded by spaces.

In the replacement use a space followed by the value of group 1.

**Find what:**

```
\h*\R\h{2,}(\S)
```

**Replace with:**

`$1`

The pattern matches:

- `\h*` Match optional horizontal whitespace characters
- `\R` Match any Unicode newline
- `\h{2,}` Match 2 or more horizontal whitespace characters
- `(\S)` Capture a single non whitespace character in **group 1**

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TS66SN/1).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The regex `\n(.+)$` would match anything following a new line character, until the end of a line. However, it seems like you want to match any 2 lines starting with 'PID', and then remove the newline in the middle.

This works: `^PID(.*)\r\n(.*)$` and `PID$1 $2`.

Note that Notepad++ uses a regex dialect that isn't very clever about `\n`, so to match a Windows newline (which is CR+LF) you have to use `\r\n` specifically (and make sure the regex enginé doesn't match newline for `.`)